# Subtract to numbers in relation to time/date specific query in Mysql // Nodered

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time, operation

hy, beeing a noob in mysql i am trying to substract two numbers in relation to a time/date specific query:

Trying to display the actual daily power consumption of my house i can extract the total input value in KWH via MODBUS using Node red from my Smart Meter. But i have to process them to see the daily consumption.

[image]

The result of the query should be:

> value inputpwr of the latest  entry of the actual day - inputpwr of  last
> entry yesterday.

So when i do this query i will get the actual daily power demand.
I was able to get the latest value, but i am failing to substract them by identifying yesterdays last entry.

```
SELECT inputpwr FROM pwrtable ORDER BY date DESC,time DESC LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone help please, im not the SQL guy.

Comment: Read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) then provide a sample with desired output according to #5 and #3. Do not forget to specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: you can use sub query to get yesterday data then can minus from today's value, right?

Comment: hy, yes (think so). but the complete query should be in one sentence, as i have to send it as one msg,topic in Node red.

Comment: Question not clear enough, Can you add the expected output

Comment: altered text, please see qoute in post. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row_number()` to add row id to every records by order desc, then the latest record will be the `rn = 1`

`Lag()` to get the previous record based on the order by date and time.

```
 with cte as (
  select s.*
  from (
     SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by _date order by _date desc, _time desc) as rn
     FROM pwrtable
  ) as s
  where rn = 1
  order by _date desc
)
select _date, inputpwr - lag(inputpwr) over (order by _date, _time) as consumption
from cte
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/sEDEPdyF)

Comment: hy, checked last two days, does its job very well. Thank you very much!!!!!